# How to increase the number of test accounts using injected Web3 with Metamask?

Tags: web3js, remix, metamask, react

I have encountered a problem where I need a large number of  accounts. How can I increase the number of accounts from only 1 with injected web3. Remix and Metamask only give 1 account. I require more than that.

Answer (score 1):

Simply make new account on metamask. Whenever you change your account, Remix updates account and switches to account.

Then from faucet receive testnet's coin or send from your first account

Comment: i got the error message : "Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
execution reverted " and my function is function addVotersList(string name,uint id , address voter) so i want to pass an address to third element of parameters .

Comment: The error you get and the topic you made are totally different problems! Provide your code in question and change the title of your question

Comment: for example the faucet from account1 and i pass account2 to the  parameter named address

Comment: The error you commented first is related to the solidity code, not to accounts. Please provide the code related to the error!

Comment: why to change the title ? the contract revert just the address and i want to add another accounts/addresses they are acceptable to injected Web3 to make the transaction done

Comment: i try the code with javascript Vm and there is no errors at all with the code :)

Comment: More accounts won't help but add metamask account by looking at here: https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015289452-How-to-create-an-additional-account-in-your-MetaMask-wallet